# Flutter: Unable to update listview builder with correct values

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have created a filter to filter UI between two dates. My problem is that the UI does not accurately reflect this, instead I notice that the former filteredList is used BUT the build .length method calculates accurately... resulting in displaying the wrong items from the list.

See code below, simplified for convenience:

*homepage.dart*

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
 void _refreshFilter() {
    setState(() => filteredList = myList.where((item) {
      DateTime date = DateTime(item.date.year, item.date.month, item.date.day);
    return date != null && (dateFilterFrom != null ? date.difference(dateFilterFrom).inDays >= 0: true) &&
        (dateFilterTo != null ? dateFilterTo.difference(date).inDays >= 0: true);})
        .toList());
    showSnackBar(context, 'Filter refreshed!');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Display(filteredList);
}
```

*display.dart*

```
class Display extends StatefulWidget {
  const Display(this.filteredList, {Key key})
      : super(key: key);
  final List filteredList;

  @override
  _DisplayState createState() => _DisplayState();
}


class _DisplayState extends State<Display> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Flexible(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: filteredList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return MyItem(index),
                ));
              }
            });
}
```

*myitem.dart*

```
class MyItem extends StatefulWidget {
  MyItem(this.index, {Key key}) : super(key: key);
  final int index;

  @override
  _MyItemState createState() => _MyItemState();
}

class _MyItemState extends State<MyItem> {
 DateTime dateTime;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlineButton(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                          onPressed: () {
                            DatePicker.showDateTimePicker(context, showTitleActions: true,
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  print('change $value in time zone ' +
                                      value.timeZoneOffset.inHours.toString());
                                }, onConfirm: (value) {
                                  print('confirm $value');
                                  setState(() {
                                    dateTime = value;
                                    filteredList[widget.index].date = value;
                                  });
                                }, currentTime: dateTime != null ? dateTime : DateTime.now());
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            dateTime != null
                                ? dateTime.toString().substring(0, 16)
                                : "select date",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                          ));
    }
}
```

`filteredList` is in globals.dart

Any tips strongly appreciated, or simply a method to have a parent widget with function that will rebuild the builder from the child widget...

NB: When I debug filteredList print the accurate items, so this is definitely a UI/state issue

Comment: hello, can you share the whole widget of the two widget if possible ?

Comment: sure gimme 2sd!

Answer (score 1):

In your `Display` widget class, add required `List` parameter, something like this:

```
class Display extends Stateless {
  final List filteredList;
  const Display({required this.filteredList});
```

Now, in your homepage where you call`Display()`, it'll ask you for the list,
So, it will look like this now:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Display(filteredList: filteredList);
```

This way, you can convert your listviewBuilder to be in a stateless widget, where you get better performance. And from your homepage, whenever you press the filter function, it'll rebuild your `Display` widget, with actual filtered list.

Comment: Thanks! I had already tried to pass the parameter to the child widget but didnt work, probably because of hot reload

Comment: Oh sorry after carefully examining it did not solve the issue, with a basic test where 2 results are filtered out of 4, the UI shows the 2 first entries (like I said the .length seems to work correctly), but use the former list, so not displaying the correct Items